# Merge two array and create new

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem to create array. I have form. 
Form's inputs are tag inputs. First input is option name. When you put any option name the new tag input added in the form.
I post data in controller and create auto variations for product. Eg. Red-S Red-M Blue-S Blue-M ... The Code which i'm using gives variation look like this:

```
array:4 [
 0 => "Red-S"
 1 => "Blue-S"
 2 => "Red-M"
 3 => "Blue-M"
]
```

And i have another array for option names

```
array:2 [
 0 => "Color"
 1 => "Size"
 ]
```

I want to create one array look like this:

```
array:2 [
 "Color" => "Red"
 "Size" => "S" 
 ]
```

This is my Controller

```
function make_combinations($props)
    {
        if ( empty($props) ) return [];
        $keys = array_keys($props);
        $key = $keys[0];
        $values = $props[$key];
        unset($props[$key]);
        $rest =  make_combinations($props);
        if ( empty($values) ) return $rest;
        if ( empty($rest) ) return $values;
        $combinations = [];

        foreach($rest as $comb)
        {
            foreach($values as $value)
            {
                $combinations[] = $value . '-' . $comb;

            }
        }
        return $combinations;
    }

    $inputs = explode(',', $request['option']);
    $props = [];

    foreach($inputs as $input)
    {
        $input_key = strtolower($input);
        if ( !$request->has($input_key) ) continue;
        $input_values = explode(',', $request->input($input_key));
        $props[$input_key] = $input_values;
    }
    $combinations = make_combinations($props);



    $result[] = compact('combinations', 'inputs');






    return view('system.modules.variants', compact('result'));
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to store normalized data into your table so you dont need to do all the things that are related to parsing serialized data?

Comment: What is in `$props`?

Comment: Props is 
array:2 [
  "color" => array:2 [
    0 => "Red"
    1 => "Blue"
  ]
  "size" => array:2 [
    0 => "S"
    1 => "m"
  ]
]

Comment: @B001ᛦ i need this array for another function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two array in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866357/merge-two-array-in-one)

Answer (score 0):

If I gessed right what are you trying to achieve, having this input:

```php
$inputs = ["Red-S-Cotton", "Blue-Silk-M"];
$keys = ['Color-Size-Material', 'Color-Material-Size'];
```

By doing a:

```php
$output = array_map(function($key) use ($inputs, $keys) {
    $expKeys = explode('-', $keys[$key]);
    $expInputs = explode('-', $inputs[$key]);
    return array_combine($expKeys, $expInputs);
}, array_keys($inputs));
```

`$output` will be:

```php
[
    [
        "Color" => "Red",
        "Size" => "S",
        "Material" => "Cotton",
    ],
    [
        "Color" => "Blue",
        "Material" => "Silk",
        "Size" => "M",
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thank for your time. But this code is not working in my system because my option names is changable size style color material and etc. and my option quantity is changable Eg Color: Red, Blue Size:S,M Material:Cotton, Silk all data random

Comment: You mean you have 3 values then, separated by dashes? Like: `Red-S-Cotton`? Whan kind of different inputs can you get?

Comment: The inputs kind is changable. First input is option name. When you put any option name the new tag input added in the form Eg. You type Material and press enter the new tag input added in form  which name is material

Comment: Do you have a limited number of colors or materials for example?

Comment: Then there is no way to know, if there is no order and no limit of inputs you can't know what is what.

Comment: i need to get first array's first value and merge it second arrays firt value 
Eg:1. Color-Size-Material  2:Red-S-Cotton  3. "Color" = "Red" do you understand me?

Comment: This gives error because $inputs is true but in $keys has only one Color-Material-Size no two only one. I want to create system when user added product option system auto add the product variations in addproduct page. i need this array because a send this data in blade and get it foreach and create simple form look like this: Eg
1 Red/S/Cotton  price:5$ sku:100 qty:200
2 Blue/S/Cotton  price:5$ sku:100 qty:200

Answer (score 0):

You can skip one loop.

You can write code something like this

```
$arr = [
 0 => "Red-S-Silk-Y",
 1 => "Blue-S",
 2 => "Red-M-Cotton",
 3 => "Blue-M",
];

$arrFinal = [];
$dataArray = [];
foreach($arr AS $value){
    $expArr = explode("-",$value);
    if(isset($expArr[0])){
      $dataArray['color'] = $expArr[0];
    }
    if(isset($expArr[1])){
      $dataArray['size'] = $expArr[1];
    }
    if(isset($expArr[2])){
      $dataArray['Material'] = $expArr[2];
    }
    if(isset($expArr[3])){
      $dataArray['Style'] = $expArr[3];
    }
    $arrFinal[] = $dataArray;
    Unset($dataArray);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrFinal);
```

Your output will be something like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [color] => Red
            [size] => S
            [Material] => Silk
            [Style] => Y
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [color] => Blue
            [size] => S
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [color] => Red
            [size] => M
            [Material] => Cotton
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [color] => Blue
            [size] => M
        )
)
```

Comment: My option name and quantity no fixed there are changable eg Color Size Material Style     Red-S-Cotton-A

Comment: @Energy40 Please find the updated code, but your sequense has to be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2,....);
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? Try to use the sample arrays given in the question as inputs, and check what `array_merge` returns. Hint: the expected result is different